# key combination c# other than hotkeys

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am implementing shortcut key combination logic like

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

but now I am looking for a trick to implement keyboard key combination without hotkey combination like : <kbd>A + D</kbd> but not getting any right things.

So please help to implement it.

**Updated**

Currently I am not able to add key combination other than hotkey combination.because whenever I am pressing two keys like : `**A + D**` it returns only single keys ascii so I am not getting two keys combination.

I have used following stuff
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/442285/Global-Shortcuts-in-WinForms-and-WPF

Comment: You might want to describe what you've tried so far. Also, WinForms, WPF?

Comment: So whats the matter? kindly explain your question!

Comment: Code is in huge amount can not post here, but please let me know if still need more details

Comment: We still don't know what tech you are using. And hotkeys without any modifier keys are most likely not supported, so you'd have to implement that logic yourself.

Comment: Added link from which I have implemented it

Answer (score 1):

In the past I used the `GetKeyState` Api (inside a similar class for catching system wide shortcuts). Perhaps new variants are available nowadays (WPF has a KeyBoard.IsKeyDown I believe), but this should still work:

```
    [DllImport("user32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto,
    ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    static extern short GetKeyState(int keyCode);

    public static bool CheckKeysPressed(params Keys[] keys)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
            if (!CheckKeyPressed((int)keys[i])) return false;
        return true;
    }
    public static bool CheckKeyPressed(Keys key)
    {
        return CheckKeyPressed((int)key);
    }
    public static bool CheckKeyPressed(int vkey)
    {
        short ks = GetKeyState(vkey);
        return ks == 1;
    }
```

Usage:  `if(CheckKeysPressed(Keys.A, Keys.D)) {/*...*/}`

Answer (score 0):

Declare 2 `bool` variable (say `IsADown` and `IsDDown`) and "`true`" them on events of both **A** and **D**. Also detect on **both events** if other `bool` is down or not. If it is, then do what you have to do with both button pressed.